# How to use the OpenCV houghcircles() output array parameter in Python

Tags: python, opencv

The OpenCV documentation for cv.houghcircles() includes an optional output vector array, denoted "circles."

cv.HoughCircles(    image, method, dp, minDist[, **circles**[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]] ) ->    circles

In no python example have I seen any use of this parameter.  And, although the nested brackets seem to require the use of the output vector parameter in order to use the following parameters, again, I've never seen it used.  I do see "circles" used as the output array such that the returned output of the method is assigned to "circles."

That is,

circles = cv2.houghcircles(img, method, dp, minDist, param1, param2, minrad, maxrad)

Is the output vector passed as a parameter into the call only used in C++, or, is there a context in python in which one would pass the output vector into the function call as it is described in the documentation?

(Also, am I correctly interpreting the nested brackets to mean that each nested level of optional parameter requires the preceding level?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is C++ API first. If you are puzzled by some of its Python API, it's because the Python bindings are generated to use the C++ API.

The C++ API `houghCircles` "returns" void. It passes the result back out via reference argument. Many other OpenCV APIs work like that. This is consistent with the way multiple results are handled in the C++ case.

`houghCircles` will always empty/clear a passed in result Mat and fill it with its own data from the algorithm. There is no reason to pass any numpy array in here. IIRC, you can pass `None`.

Python bindings generation collects all output-tagged parameters into the returned result tuple. Generation also fills `OutputArray` parameters with implicitly created empty Mats, if there was no argument or no default argument specified in the C++ API itself.

Yes, the nesting of square brackets implies optional arguments. You can skip any you don't want by using named/keyword arguments, like so (use imagination for the ...):

```
circles = cv.houghCircles(image, method=..., dp=..., minDist=..., minRadius=...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  After thinking through your answer, I did find a description of the python binding approach in the documentation, although it is complex for a novice.

https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html

For anyone else struggling to implement methods based on the official documentation (particularly which outputs are actually implemented in the python wrapper)...the python tutorials show the intended usage, at least for the functions explicitly demonstrated.  E.g.,

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html

And similar articles for each of the sections and subsections.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html

Thanks again, Rackwitz, for the informative answer.